# how to get the current added in the table without getting all the data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

guys im trying to make a simple commenting system, that when i click the submit the fields will automatically save in the database then fetch it using ajax. but im getting all the data repeatedly instead of getting the recently added data in the database here is the code:

```
 <div id="wrap-body">    
  <form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
 <div id="info">
 </div>
 </div> 
<script>
 $(document).ready(function (){
$('#submit').click(function (){
 var username = $('#username').val();
  var msg = $('#msg').val();
  if(username != "" && msg != ""){
       $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'get.php',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data:{ 'username' : username , 'msg' : msg},
                  success: function (data){
                    var ilan=data[0].counter;
                    var i = 0;
                      for(i=0;i<=ilan;i++){
                       $('#info').append("<p> you are:"+data[i].username+"</p> <p> your message  is:"+data[i].mesg);
                     }
                  }
              });
     }
     else{
      alert("some fields are required");
     }
 });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
   <?php
   $host='localhost';
   $username='root';
   $password='12345';
   $db = 'feeds';

    $connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cant connect");
    mysql_select_db($db) or die("cant select the".$db);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];

    $insert = "INSERT INTO info(user_name,message) VALUES('$username','$msg')";
    if(@!mysql_query($insert)){
      die('error insertion'.mysql_error());
  }
    $get = "SELECT * FROM info ";
    $result=mysql_query($get)or die(mysql_error()); 
    $inside_counter =   mysql_num_rows($result);
    $data=array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
  $data[] = array(
    'username'=>$row['user_name'],
    'mesg'=>$row['message'],
    'counter'=>$inside_counter
   );
   }
    echo json_encode($data);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM "table_name" 
ORDER BY "id" desc 
LIMIT 1
```

This is a SQL query to get last record from table. It return last inserted according to `id`. `id` should be a auto increment field. I think this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are returning all the row in the table again to the ajax call via

```
$get = "SELECT * FROM info ";
```

if you do return all of them again you will have to test if they are not already there before appending them with the jQuery
Perhaps only return the newly inserted row.

or

The jQuery already knows the data it sent to the server, just return success true or false, and then append it if true with the jQuery, no need to return the data back again to the client side

EDIT

I'm not going to write code for you but perhaps these suggestions may help

```
mysql_query($insert)
```

link here for reference - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

will return true of false depending on if the insert statement was successful

you could potentially also check that it acutally inserted a row by calling

```
mysql_affected_rows()
```

link here for reference - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

then assuming that the insert was successful (i.e. true from  mysql_query($insert) or mysql_affected_rows() > 0) simply return successful (i.e. something like

```
 echo json_encode(true);
```

then on the client side you could do something like the following:

(jQuery Ajax success function only:)

```
  success: function (data){
        if (data) {
            $('#info').append("<p> you are:"+username +"</p> <p> your message  is:"+msg);
        }
        else
        {
             alert('There has been an error saving your message');
        }
    }
```

using the variables that you just used to send the request

(Please note code samples provided here are only for example, not intended to be used verbatim)

Couple of points though. Is your intention to post the data via ajax only? (i.e. no page refresh) as if that is the case, you will need to return false from you form submit event handler to stop the page full posting. Also you do not appear to have any logic, or are not worried about complete duplicates being entered (i.e. same username, same message) - not sure if you want to worry about this.

I would also potentially look at tracking all the messages via ids (although I don't know your DB structure), perhaps using

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

link here FYI  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

That way each message can have a unique id, may be easier to establish duplicates, even if the username and message are identical

There are numerous ways to deal with this.

Anyway hope that helps

PS - using the mysql_ - group of commands is generally discouraged these days, use the mysqli_ range of function instead

Comment: how to do such thing?. can you help me with the codings im still a newbie with jquery and php. hope u understand

Comment: OJay gave you a ton of advice, so you'll need to be more specific. Try to specify what you don't understand. Or, if you've been able to make some progress, try to figure out the specific problem that's stopping you and post a new question about that.

Comment: i got some codes on how not to get the passed iteration as it stated on the document but my problem now is im having }); error in the firebug here is the code: $.each(data, function(i,item) {

                     $('#info').append("<p> you are:"+data[item].username+"</p> <p> your message  is:"+data[i].mesg);

                   });​

my problem now is how to solve the }); problem.  i checked the }); if i supply them correctly and they all have the correct }); ending but not on this $.each

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with $.each? The code is a bit hard to read in the comments, try editing your question and added the new code to your question so I can see it better

Comment: someone suggested me to use it so that the only currently added data in the table will be get by the ajax. here is the complete codes of mine. http://pastebin.com/HCDweLm6